# Initialize Surface View via data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm working with [this network graph library](https://github.com/Giwi/android-network-graph).
I have a `GraphSurfaceView` in my layout.
This `view` displays graph by giving a `NetworkGraph` object to it, something like this:

```
graphSurface.init(networkGraph)
```

How can I bind `networkGraph` data to `graphSurface` in MVVM architecture?

I tried this code below and it didn't work, I should call `init` after creating my `networkGraph`:

`BindingUtils.kt`

```
@BindingAdapter("networkGraph")
@JvmStatic
fun setNetworkGraph(view: GraphSurfaceView, networkGraph: NetworkGraph) {
    view.init(networkGraph)
}
```

`myActivity.kt`

```
relationActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, getLayoutId())
graphSurface = relationActivityBinding.graphSurface
```

`viewModel.kt`

```
fun getNetworkGraph() = this.graphManager?.getGraphNetwork() // returns my networkGraph
```

`activity.xml`

```
<giwi.org.networkgraph.GraphSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/graphSurface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:networkGraph="@{viewModel.getNetworkGraph()}"/>
```

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: yeah I got `E/SurfaceView: Exception configuring surface
    java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero` because my networkGraph has no item in it at the first moment @Emil

Comment: I usually create a setter method in the View itself instead of a binding adapter. Please try this inside GraphSurfaceView. `fun setNetworkGraph(networkGraph: NetworkGraph?) {
    view.init(networkGraph)
}`

Comment: Then how and where to set `networkGraph` to my `GraphSurfaceView`? actually I can't set my `networkGraph` inside my activity, because of MVVM architecture.

Comment: yeah, I understand, Just use the same attribute in the xml for binding. instead of the binding adapter method I am suggesting a setter method in the View.

Comment: sorry I just use learning MVVM & data binding, if u explain more for me I would appreciate @Emil